# how to acess nested STDClasses with the string path in php?

Tags: php, stdclass

Imagine you have a variable `$a` which is Stdclass with nested Stdclasses and so on, like the following:

```
<?php
$json = '{ "foo": {
    "foo":{
            "foo":"bar"
    }
} }';
$a = json_decode($json);
$b="foo.foo.foo";

print_r($a->foo->foo->foo);
print_r($$b});

?>
```

Now in the variable `$b` I have the path that I want to access.

Is there a way to tell PHP to get the value for that path?

Comment: Dot syntax isn't supported in PHP. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode on dot, then iterate, using each segment as an object property.

```
$path = explode('.', $b);

$current = $a;
foreach ($path as $segment) {
    $current = $current->$segment;
}

var_dump($current);   // bar
```

If the path contains segments that don't map properly to the object properties, you'll get undefined property notices and end up with a `null` value.

Note that this will only work for nested objects. If your input JSON includes arrays at any level this can't handle it, and you'll need something a bit more complex.